# NOT LIKE (with an exception) in MySQL WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I have a table with surnames, some contain 'Dr.', 'Sr.', 'Jr.', etc. I want to exclude any name with a full stop anywhere in the string, but retain those that contain 'St.', there are over 100,000 rows.

I've tried this and failed:

```
SELECT surname FROM surnames 
WHERE surname NOT LIKE '%.%' 
AND surname NOT IN (SELECT surname FROM surnames WHERE surname LIKE '%St.%')
```

Comment: Is this you need `SELECT surname FROM surnames WHERE surname NOT LIKE '%.%' OR surname LIKE '%St.%'`

Comment: Ah, so simple. I can't believe I missed it. Thank you!

Comment: For performance though, I suggest adding a field "title", and store these titles in it. i.e. separate title from surname

Comment: In an ideal world I would love to be working with clean data, Jehad! I would also love to be in bed, given the questions I'm posting on here at the moment ;-)